# Cannot access memory at address 0x0 when returning an array of strings from a function

Tags: c, malloc

I send a pointer to an array of char* to a function (args).  In that function I set the value to the first two postions in the array to malloc'd strings.  When I return to the orignal calling function where the array itself was malloc'd, the last position of the array gives me a "Cannot access memory at address 0x0".  Am I doing somthing wrong in malloc/realloc/ or storing the values?

Calling Function:

```
int bufspace = 0; /* bytes in table */

    ...

args = emalloc(BUFSIZ); /* initialize array */
bufspace = BUFSIZ;     //size=8192
spots = BUFSIZ / sizeof(char *);

while (*cp != '\0') //While not at the end
    cp = read_segment(cp, &len, &indollarsign, &argnum, start, &args, &prev_char_escape);
    start = cp;
    len = 0;

    if (argnum + 1 >= spots) {
        args = erealloc(args, bufspace + BUFSIZ);
        bufspace += BUFSIZ;
        spots += (BUFSIZ / sizeof(char *));
        }
    }
```

Called Function (read_segment) - First called to store at position 0 then at position 1:

```
*args[*argnum] = newstr(start, *len); //Generate the string through malloc
```

At this line, I have strings in these positions: *args[0] and *args[1]

But as soon as I return to the calling function
args[0] has a string but args[1] shows a "Cannot access memory at address 0x0"

Comment: Why passing the address of `args` in `read_segment`? What is the type of `argnum`? We don't have the code of `read_segment()` and `newstr()`.

Comment: It's very hard to answer a question if you don't tell us what the types are and if you only show part of the code.

Comment: If you could add the relevant definitions of `read_segment`, the problem would become more clear. Also `sizeof(char*)` would be fixed (either 4 for 32 bit or 8 for 64 bit architechture) so spots would increment by a constant factor (of 4 or 8) in every iteration.

Comment: args is type char** in the calling function.  It's sent to read_segment as &args so in read_segment the type is char***.  newstr just returns a malloc's string of type char*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*args[*argnum]` dereferences the pointer at `args[*argnum]`. I think you meant

```
(*args)[*argnum] = newstr(start, *len);
```